# How to handle an Event of a programmatically created object?

Tags: iphone, event-handling

That's a very basic question.

How can I catch for example the "touchesBegan" event of a UIWindow instance? So that whenever the user is touching the window a method I set is called?

Thank you!

F.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For iOS 3.2+: Create a gesture recognizer and add it to the view you are interested in.

Comment: Ole, thank you for your reply. There isn't a generic way as there is in C#; event handling for any kind of events triggered from class instances?

Comment: Not really. To catch all events in your app, subclass `UIApplication` and override `-sendEvent:`.

Comment: Oh I see.. pity! :P Thank you for the info! F.

Answer (score 0):

Posting the tutorial that got my head around Gesture Recognisers:
http://www.conceitedcode.com/2010/06/implementing-gesture-recognizers/

F.